# SQL - Conditional Where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have the following table and data:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (id int, city varchar(10), ref varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Temp (id, city, ref)
SELECT 1, 'London', 'GBP' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'London', 'EUR' 

SELECT  *
FROM    @Temp
WHERE ((city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP') OR (city = 'London' AND ref <> 'GBP'))
```

This returns:

```
1 London GBP
2 London EUR
```

What I would like to do is to check for where city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP' first, if there is no row qualifying this then check if the city is London and ref can be anything, tried using case when but did not quite work.

In this scenario I should only get the row #1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just return the rows not containing GBP when there are no GPB rows, using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Temp
WHERE (city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP') OR (city = 'London' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  *
            FROM    @Temp
            WHERE city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP'))
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7814/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with single record, then next should work:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    @Temp
WHERE city = 'London'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ref = 'GBP' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: TOP 1 by default doesn't return ties. OP problem description is not very clear, I assumed that he always wants to return only single row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM @Temp
WHERE city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM @Temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Temp 
    WHERE city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP'
) AND city = 'London'
```

`SELECT` after `UNION` is conditional where.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM @Temp
WHERE 
  CASE
   WHEN city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP' THEN 1
   WHEN city = 'London' AND ref <> 'GBP' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Temp
                                                        WHERE city = 'London' 
                                                        AND ref = 'GBP') THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END = 1
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379509)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
select city, max(ref)
from @Temp
group by city
```

Alternatively

```
select city, ref
from @Temp t1
where t1.ref = 'GBP'
   or not exists (select 1 from @Temp t2
                  where t2.city = t1.city
                    and t2.ref = 'GBP')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `NOT EXISTS` something like:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Temp
WHERE ((city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP') OR (city = 'London' AND ref <> 'GBP'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM  @Temp
                      WHERE city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP')))
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work: ordering by id doesn't guarantee that the GBP will be the first row (in this case yes, but this certainly won't be the case everytime).

Comment: Same with ref, what if some other currency exists named, say, USD ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can deal with ordering in the case like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM @Temp t 
    CROSS APPLY -- The ordering logic write here
    (
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN (city = 'London' AND ref = 'GBP') THEN 1
                WHEN (city = 'London' AND ref <> 'GBP') THEN 2
                -- Not match at all
            END AS Value
    ) orders
WHERE orders.Value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN orders.Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    orders.Value
```